# Select nonadjacent lines containing a common phrase in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an HTML file that has around 700 of my bookmarks. Each line has link and  a tag like the following:

```
<li><a href="https://www.bartleby.com/141/" time_added="1547558810" tags="paper_writing">Strunk, William, Jr. 1918. The Elements of Style</a></li>
```

The file has multiple lines with the same tags. I want to group the lines with the same tag next to each other. I was trying to do it in vscode. I can select multiple occurrences of the same phrase with `Ctrl+Shift+L`, but I could not select the lines. Is there a way for doing this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After your comment below that clarified what you are trying to do I think you will find this easier than your solution.

1. Select the text to check.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> selects all occurrences.  The command is `Select All Occurrences of Find Match` - if that is bound to something else on your OS, use that.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> will select the entire line. ([Changed](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/67178) from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> in Feb. 2019.)  That is using the command `Expand Line Selection` - again find that command in your `Keyboard Shortcuts` and use the same command.
4. Cut and paste them where you want.

There is also an extension [vscode-dup-checker](https://github.com/jianbingfang/vscode-dup-checker) that will find and **delete** duplicate lines.  I don't know if you actually want to delete the duplicates though.

I added a gif to show it in action - it only uses steps 1-4 above:

[image: demo of selecting all common lines]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe my question was not clear, but I wanted to cut the lines which share only one phrase that is common between those lines. When I followed your answer, I could only cut the common phrase but not the whole line.

Comment: When you say "one phrase" in common do you mean have at least one attribute (like "tags") or the attribute value ("paper_writing") or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant `tags="paper_writing"`, for example. I agree it is not a phrase but was not sure of what to call it.

Comment: I am confused, so I added a gif to show it in action with the keystrokes I mentioned.  Ctrl-I (that is an "eye")  does select the entire line of the common phrase - "tags='paper_writing'" in this case.

Comment: Great! Home and Shift+End now reduced to Ctrl+I . This is better, accepting your answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I don't see an OS mention in question or the answer, but  I'm on MacOS.

Comment: On MacOS, this doesn't work on VS Code June 2022 (using Command key instead of Ctrl)

Comment: @blitter @majorgear I edited the answer to show the command names involved.  What is  `Select All Occurrences of Find` bound to on your system?  And what is `Expand Line Selection` bound to?  Use those keybindings.    And which step doesn't work, 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found one method that works. I don't know if it the best though.

After `Ctrl+Shift+L`, you have cursors on all the lines with that phrase. Then pressing `Home` will take you to the beginning of all of them and `Shift+End` then will select all those lines on which you have the cursor. Then cut the text and paste it wherever you wish. Came out to be pretty useful for me while I was editing a html file with 700 links.